# Converting date in string to NSDate type giving wrong Month and Year in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I have a array of dictionaries and each dictionary also has a `date` key like `doj:"2014-10-11"` along with other `key:value` pairs as well.So what I am trying to do is group the data from same month and year together in one `tableViewSection` and set the title of the `tableView` section as `October 2014` (from the above date).However I am stuck at converting the date in string format to `NSDate` type which on conversion is giving me wrong month and year.

```
  - (void)setupDataSource:(NSArray*)bookingArray
  {
     self.tableViewSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
     self.tableViewCells = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];

     NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
     NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter_table = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
     dateFormatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone;

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    [dateFormatter_table setDateFormat:@"MMMM YYYY"];

    NSUInteger dateComponents = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;
    NSInteger previousYear = -1;
    NSInteger previousMonth = -1;
    NSMutableArray* tableViewCellsForSection = nil;

    for (NSDictionary *dictObject in bookingList) {
        NSString *dateString = [dictObject objectForKey:@"doj"];   //gives "2014-10-11"
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        NSString *tempDate = [dateFormatter_table stringFromDate:date];

        NSLog(@"Table Header Date : %@", tempDate);         //gives October 2014 properly
        NSDateFormatter *newformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [newformatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM YYYY"];
        NSDate *dateForTable = [newformatter dateFromString:tempDate];

        NSLog(@"Table Header Date : %@", dateForTable);    //gives December 2013

        NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:dateComponents fromDate:dateForTable];


       NSInteger year = [components year];
       NSInteger month = [components month];

       if (year != previousYear || month != previousMonth)
       {
          NSString* sectionHeading = [newformatter stringFromDate:dateForTable];
          [self.tableViewSections addObject:sectionHeading];
          tableViewCellsForSection = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
          [self.tableViewCells setObject:tableViewCellsForSection forKey:sectionHeading];
          previousYear = year;
          previousMonth = month;

      }
      [tableViewCellsForSection addObject:dateForTable];

    }


 }
```

Comment: Use 'yyyy' for the year, not 'YYYY'.

Comment: See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)